# Ordering independent variables in relation to the dependent variable

Tags: data-science, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I am building a regression model with some of the following variables:

- Dependent variable named 'Churned'. This contains either 1 or 0. 1 if they churned and 0 if they did not.
- Independent variable named 'How happy with the service'. This is on a scale 1-10 with 1 being very unhappy and 10 being very happy.

As the dependent variable is phrased in a negative light (i.e. To churn rather than to stay) would the independent variable need to have it's scale reversed so that the more negative value is 10 and the positive value is 1?

My theory is that by reversing the scale of the independent variable the higher the coefficient score from the model would mean that it would show whether a less favourable rating would drive churn.

Answer (score 0):

It won't matter if you would rank it in ascending order or descending order; as long as you have a specified order of the categories your machine learning model will be able to train the data. But you would still have to keep in mind the scale for "How happy with the service" column when you feed the data after you have trained to identify whether a customer will churn or not. You can read more about ordinal data on wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_data

Another perspective here could be what if you just change the name of the column from "How happy with the service" to "How dissatisfied with the service". Would you still be thinking to change the scale? No, right.